# How to access configs from autoloaded config files in a layout / view script in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: configuration, zend-framework2, production-environment, application-settings

I would like / have to manage some settings in [ZF1 style](http://blog.evan.pro/environment-specific-configuration-in-zend-framework-2) and provide the view with the infomation about the current environment.

**/config/application.config.php**

```
return array(
    ...
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        ...
        'config_glob_paths' => array('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php')
    )
);
```

**/config/autoload/env.local.php**

```
return array(
    // allowed values: development, staging, live
    'environment' => 'development'
);
```

In a common view script I can do it over the controller, since the controllers have access to the Service Manager and so to all configs I need:

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function myAction() {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'currentEnvironment' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['environment'],
        ));
    }

}
```

Is it also possible to get the configs in a common view directly?

**How can I access the configs in a layout view script (`/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml`)?**

Comment: I'd suggest a view helper that's injected with the config, substitute the model class with config in the answer I just gave here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082529/calling-a-method-in-model-from-layout-in-zendframework-2, and use your helper as a proxy

Comment: Definitely the approach provided by @Crisp however there'd be strong questions about why you would really need them. A view should render, nothing else, it shouldn't even bother about any single config. That's the controllers job. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You could certainly use both those methods, but I would tend to keep it out of the view as Sam suggests :)

Comment: @Sam I want to permit displaying the web analytics JS within the dev/staging environment.

Comment: Definitely a solution for a viewHelper `displayAnalytics()` - the viewHelper would access the config via ServiceManager and then either output an empty string or the functional analytics code. See answer provided by crisp ;)

Comment: Thank you guys! +1 for Cris for a solution hint and +2 for Sam for a reasonable notice about handling of views and another solution hint. :) I've implemented now the first solution and will also try it with the second one. I see, that the `displayAnalytics()` view helper way is cleaner and better for my concret case. But the original question was "How to access configs from autoloaded config files in a layout / view script [...] ?". So, I'll post both solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(My implementation/interpretation of) [Crisp's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083256/how-to-access-configs-from-autoloaded-config-files-in-a-layout-view-script-in#comment22959752_16083256):

**Config view helper**

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager as ServiceManager;

class Config extends AbstractHelper {

    protected $serviceManager;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        $config = $this->serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
        return $config;
    }

}
```

**Application `Module` class**

```
public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'config' => function($serviceManager) {
                $helper = new \MyNamespace\View\Helper\Config($serviceManager);
                return $helper;
            },
        )
    );
}
```

**Layout view script**

```
// do whatever you want with $this->config()['environment'], e.g.
<?php
if ($this->config()['environment'] == 'live') {
    echo $this->partial('partials/partial-foo.phtml');;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation/interpretation of [Sam's solution hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083256/how-to-access-configs-from-autoloaded-config-files-in-a-layout-view-script-in/16085971#comment22961439_16083256) for the concret goal (to permit displaying the web analytics JS within the dev/staging environment):

**DisplayAnalytics view helper**

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager as ServiceManager;

class DisplayAnalytics extends AbstractHelper {

    protected $serviceManager;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        if ($this->serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['environment'] == 'development') {
            $return = $this->view->render('partials/partial-bar.phtml');
        }
        return $return;
    }

}
```

**Application `Module` class**

```
public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'displayAnalytics' => function($serviceManager) {
                $helper = new \MyNamespace\View\Helper\DisplayAnalytics($serviceManager);
                return $helper;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

**Layout view script**

```
<?php echo $this->displayAnalytics(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16085971/2019043) becomes more flexible:

**/config/application.config.php**

```
return array(
    ...
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        ...
        'config_glob_paths' => array('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php')
    )
);
```

**/config/autoload/whatever.local.php** and **/config/autoload/whatever.global.php**

```
return array(
    // allowed values: development, staging, live
    'environment' => 'development'
);
```

**ContentForEnvironment view helper**

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager as ServiceManager;

class ContentForEnvironment extends AbstractHelper {

    protected $serviceManager;

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    /**
     * Returns rendered partial $partial,
     * IF the current environment IS IN $whiteList AND NOT IN $blackList,
     * ELSE NULL.
     * Usage examples:
     * Partial for every environment (equivalent to echo $this->view->render($partial)):
     *  echo $this->contentForEnvironment('path/to/partial.phtml');
     * Partial for 'live' environment only:
     *  echo $this->contentForEnvironment('path/to/partial.phtml', ['live']);
     * Partial for every environment except 'development':
     *  echo $this->contentForEnvironment('path/to/partial.phtml', [], ['development', 'staging']);
     * @param string $partial
     * @param array $whiteList
     * @param array $blackList optional
     * @return string rendered partial $partial or NULL.
     */
    public function __invoke($partial, array $whiteList, array $blackList = []) {
        $currentEnvironment = $this->serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['environment'];
        $content = null;
        if (!empty($whiteList)) {
            $content = in_array($currentEnvironment, $whiteList) && !in_array($currentEnvironment, $blackList)
                ? $this->view->render($partial)
                : null
            ;
        } else {
            $content = !in_array($currentEnvironment, $blackList)
                ? $this->view->render($partial)
                : null
            ;
        }
        return $content;
    }

}
```

**Application `Module` class**

```
public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'contentForEnvironment' => function($serviceManager) {
                $helper = new \MyNamespace\View\Helper\ContentForEnvironment($serviceManager);
                return $helper;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

**Layout view script**

```
<?php echo $this->contentForEnvironment('path/to/partial.phtml', [], ['development', 'staging']); ?>
```